# Кнопка назад в браузере не работает должным образом после использования ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, браузер

Когда я нажимаю "Назад"в браузере, я вижу код JS ответа вместо предыдущей страницы.
Есть ли способ заставить кнопку "Назад" работать, чтобы переход шел на предыдущую страницу, а не оставался на этой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите связанный с проблемой код и точную последовательность действий, которая приводит к появлению проблемы, чтобы мы смогли повторить у себя и понять о чём вообще речь

Comment: Угадываю: Вы используете метод GET в своих запросах, при этом Вы изменяете вручную адресную строку. После ухода с этой страницы и возращения - браузер шлет на сервер ту адресную строку, которую Вы до этого туда вставили. А сервер не понимает, что от него хотят html-страницу и думает, что это ajax-запрос - со всеми вытекающими